# How to find opposite and adjacent lengths of a right triangle given the hypotenuse and angle?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I'm writing a few functions for a JavaScript game engine.  Is it possible to calculate the length of the legs of a right triangle given ONLY the length of the hypotenuse and an angle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes, I believe so. Use the sin formula:
$$c=\dfrac{b}{\sin B}=\dfrac{a}{\sin A}\\
\implies b=c\sin B,\quad a=c\sin A$$
Given $\angle A\text{ or }\angle B $ we can calculate the other angle (right triangle).

Comment: Gotta love the good ol' ASA.  Thanks for the memory jog!

Comment: @JesseMillar Yes, well, I was teaching some basic trig. to my friends, and so this popped up to my mind immediately!

Answer (score 1):

Two words for you: **sine** and **cosine**

[image]

Comment: As nice as it would be if this worked, I don't believe it will in the programming sphere.  For example, Math.sin(45) in JavaScript returns 0.8509035245341184.  Unless there's some way to break that decimal into the opposite and adjacent values, it won't do me any good.

Comment: Hmm, then I think you should specify that in the question, because then you would get answers like these.

Comment: Three words? *sine*, *and*, *cosine*! :-)

Comment: @PandaBear This was the first question I've ever asked on Stack.  Thanks for the tip.  :)

Comment: @JesseMillar Have you heard of other stack exchange websites like stack overflow? If the problem you are having is java related, then maybe you can get an answer there.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar sine and cosine are in bold, mind you! ;-)

Comment: @PandaBear I have indeed.  I've been lurking Stack Overflow for a couple years now.  Just wanted to give this one a shot first.